# Adaptive bitrate streaming protocol (for any data)

Tags: streaming, live-streaming, network-protocols

I'm looking for some ideas/hints for streaming protocol (similar to video/audio streaming) to send any data in so called real-time.

In simple words:

- I'm producing some data each second (let's say one array with 1MB of data per second) and I'm sorting that data from most important to not so important (like putting them to priority queues or similar)
- I would like to keep streaming those data via some protocol and in perfect case I would like to send all of it
- If not possible (bandwidth, dropping packets etc.) I would like to send from each produced array as much as possible (first n-bytes) just to keep data going (it is important to start sending new produced array each second).

And now - I'm looking for such protocol/library that will handle adaptive bit rate stuff for any data. I would expect from it to tell me how much data I can send (put into send buffers or similar approach). The most similar thing is video/audio streaming when in poor network conditions (en)coder is changing quality depending on network conditions.
It is also OK if I miss some send data (so UDP deep down of this stuff is OK) but preferably I would like to send as much data as possible per second without loosing anything (from those first n-bytes send).

Do you have any ideas of what protocol/libraries I could use for client/server? (hopefully some libs in python, C or C++).

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything generic, as the way the experience degrades is very specific to the use case.  For example, latency plays a very important part here, as does things like segment size and desired reliability.  (For example, if several of your "high priority" chunks don't make it in a certain amount of time, do you need to buffer until you get them?  Or, can you skip and continue?)

Comment: @Brad: I would say if anything bad happens (so if sent data regardless of its priority is lost) just continue and do not repeat or buffer. That is why I think that I need similar (same?) underlying protocols as for audio or video streaming. I just don't want to reinvent all the mechanisms that keep data flowing with as much bandwidth as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think [IPFIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Flow_Information_Export) (the generic NetFlow standard) has everything you need.

You can avoid a timestamp per sample by sending a [samplingInterval](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipfix/ipfix.xhtml#:%7E:text=34-,samplingInterval,-unsigned32) update every time you change your rate. You can also add other updating the change in sampling asynchronously.

As for where to put your data. You can create a new field or just use an existing one with that has a datatype you want. IE: if you are just sending uint64 sample values then it might be easier to use `packetDeltaCount` then create your own field definition.

There are plenty of IPFIX [libraries](https://github.com/CESNET/ipfixcol2).